# Trying to disable bootstrap-fullscreen-select using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a python flask server to control a project I am working on.

I have discovered bootstrap-fullscreen-select and it is exactly what I am looking for to use as my control page, I need to disable one of the elements depending on a radio button result but alas every js command I try I can't get the select to disable.

I have attached my current stripped down test code, if anyone can offer any suggestion I would be very grateful, (I am a beginner so please be gentle)

```
<form id="row1Radio" action="">
<p>Single or Dual Display:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="r1_disp" value="1"> Single
  <input type="radio" name="r1_disp" value="2"> Dual
</form>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">Right Display</div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <select id="sel1" class="mobileSelect" name="abc" method="GET"         action="/">
    {% for colour in colours %}
        <option value= "{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colour}}</option>"
        {% endfor %}
</select>

  </div>
</div>

$('input[name=r1_disp]').change(function(){
    if (this.value == 1) {
        // alert("TRUE");
        $('#sel1').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#sel1').mobileSelect('refresh');
    } else {
        // alert("FALSE");
        $('#sel1').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#sel1').mobileSelect('refresh');
    }
})
```

Comment: can you tell me that what you want to disable on which radio button?

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked your code a little bit to give you an idea how to do it
Try this code, It'll work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CSS Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="">
        <p>Single or Dual Display:</p>
          <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="1" onchange="myFunction()"> Single
          <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r2" value="2" onchange="myFunction2()"> Dual
    </form>    
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Right Display</div>
        <div class="panel-body">    
          <select id="sel1" class="mobileSelect" name="abc" method="GET"  action="/">
            {% for colour in colours %}
            <option value= "{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colour}}</option>"
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("r1").value;
        if (x==1) {
          document.getElementById("sel1").disabled = true;
        }
      }
      function myFunction2() {
        var x = document.getElementById("r2").value;
        if (x==2) {
          document.getElementById("sel1").disabled = false;
        }
      }

    </script>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have included more of my code, I am not using regular bootstrap but bootstrap-fullscreen-select http://craftpip.github.io/bootstrap-fullscreen-select/

Comment: Okay No worries !, I'll try for that